# Gitlab - How to limit users inherited roles to lesser role in a subgroup

Tags: gitlab, permissions, roles

In gitlab, I would like to use a subgroup to limit access to a certain subproject. As it stands right now, we can only create projects within our group, which is “abc/zzz” lets say. Any project created within “abc/zzz” automatically gets the permission assigned to group “abc/zzz”.

So if I create “abc/zzz/yyy”, “yyy” inherits all the permissions from “abc/zzz”.

Even if I create a subgroup “abc/zzz/yyy”, I can’t edit the roles to limit access to a specified user or users.

Is there any way around this other than creating deleting the users from the inherited group and creating a bunch of subgroups and assigning the specific projects to them?

Comment: There is not. Inheritance is built-in and not configurable. There's a feature request for it: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/383662